# derive the distribution

Tags: regression, distributions

(Multiple regression model with p's predictor variables.)

Derive the distribution of

$$\frac{(b-\beta)X'X(b-\beta)}{MSE\cdot p}$$

As far as I know,

$b\sim N(\beta,\sigma^2 (X'X)^{-1})$

$b-\beta \sim N(0,\sigma^2 (X'X)^{-1})$

$\displaystyle\frac{b-\beta}{\sigma} \sim N(0,(X'X)^{-1})$

$\displaystyle\frac{X(b-\beta)}{\sigma } \sim N(0,X(X'X)^{-1}X')$

$\displaystyle\frac{(b-\beta)'X'X(b-\beta)}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2(\text{rank}(X'X);\delta=0)$ **

Since $X'X$ is full rank, $\text{rank}(X'X)=p$ **

Thus, $\displaystyle\frac{(b-\beta)'X'X(b-\beta)}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2(p)$

Since we don't know about the parameter $\sigma^2$, plug in MSE in place of that.

It becomes approximately $\displaystyle\frac{(b-\beta)'X'X(b-\beta)}{MSE}\sim \chi^2(p)$ **

And finally dividing p, we get $\displaystyle\frac{(b-\beta)'X'X(b-\beta)}{MSE\cdot p}\sim \chi^2(1)$ **

The mark "**" means I'm not sure because of my lack of mathematical justification.
Also I'm not sure whether this solution is correct.(the solution is from me, of course.)
Is there anybody who can help me get the answer and improve my statistical skills?

Comment: You start okay. But looking at your last line, dividing a $\chi^2(p)$ by $p$ does *not* give a $\chi^2(1)$. Going up a few lines, MSE is a random variable, not a constant, so dividing by it means you're looking at the ratio of two random variables. There's a [result that may be useful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem#Alternative_formulation). Then you need to know something about ratios of independent chi-square random variables divided by their df.

Comment: @Glen_b Oh, really good answer. good. Okay. But what gives $\chi^2(p)$ divided by $p$?

Comment: Don't worry about the "divided by p" until the end, when you need it. First worry about the denominator and the independence of numerator and denominator.

Comment: @Glen_b There's a question. As far as I know, MSE is a scalar and so it has a specific value. Then what makes you say that MSE is a random variable?

Comment: Because it's a function of the data. $\bar{y}$ is also a scalar, and yet it's a random variable. MSE = $\sum_i(y_i-\hat{y_i})^2/(n-p)$ is a function of the data, and so a random variable also.

Comment: @Glen_b I see.. thx!

Comment: So may I know the correct answer? If you wouldn't mind typing all the stuff. It seems difficult to figure out things to me.

Comment: @Glen_b I think I finally got the answer. You wanted me to apply F distribution. right? To do that I should check the independence of the denominator and the numerator as well. :)

Comment: Yes, but recall that I explained something about a result that "may be useful"... have a close look at it.